Azure ARM template for OpenAi, specify the type of OpenAI
is it possible to specify the type of openAi I want in the arm template? I would like to specify that I need gpt4o Below a snippet from my arm template:
{
  "type": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts",
  "apiVersion": "2024-04-01-preview",
  "name": "[parameters('accounts_aichatboxopenai_name')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "sku": {
    "name": "S0"
  },
  "kind": "OpenAI",
  "properties": {
    "customSubDomainName": "[parameters('accounts_aichatboxopenai_name')]",
    "networkAcls": {
      "defaultAction": "Allow",
      "virtualNetworkRules": [],
      "ipRules": []
    },
    "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled"
  }
},


As far as I have tested, we are unable to directly set the type of OpenAI.
Here are the results to run az cognitiveservices account list-kinds.
[
  "AIServices",
  "AnomalyDetector",
  "CognitiveServices",
  "ComputerVision",
  "ContentModerator",
  "ContentSafety",
  "ConversationalLanguageUnderstanding",
  "CustomVision.Prediction",
  "CustomVision.Training",
  "Face",
  "FormRecognizer",
  "HealthInsights",
  "ImmersiveReader",
  "Internal.AllInOne",
  "LUIS.Authoring",
  "LanguageAuthoring",
  "MetricsAdvisor",
  "OpenAI",
  "Personalizer",
  "QnAMaker.v2",
  "SpeechServices",
  "TextAnalytics",
  "TextTranslation"
]

Here is the document of the ARM template definition for resource Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts.
